# The Normal distribution:problem solving

Tags: statistics

Suppose you were informed that the annual income of lawyers is normally distributed, with a mean of $40,000$ and a standard deviation of $10,000$. What percent of lawyers earn more than $60,000$?

Comment: What do you know about normal distributions? $20 000$ is $2$ S.D. away, so...

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Are you familiar with the empirical rule? It could be used to estimate the answer. How do you usually compute normal probabilities? Z-values and a table? Or software?

Answer (score 0):

Actually income can not follow a strict normal distribution since it can not be less than 0 (generally). Here for the given distribution we have,
$$
P(income\leq0) = 0.0000316712
$$
Anyway you can ignore it, it is easy to get the probability of income beyond 60,000
$$
P(income > 60000 ) = 0.0227501
$$